# Allow SSH from PowerShell without Administrator privileges

Tags: powershell, ssh, opensshutils

**I mean to get a terminal in an Ubuntu 20.04LTS server via ssh under PS 5.1 in Win 10**.
I know I can work with [native support for OpenSSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse), and I have already done it before.

Now **I want to do it without having admin rights**, to minimize "tainting" my system.
For reasons described below (1), I think I cannot work with native OpenSSH.

For reasons described below (2), I think it is possible.
For instance, I can already start a session and issue remote commands [ref](https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2016/04/using-ssh-with-powershell/), see below (3).
But I couldn't start a terminal.

**Is there a way to accomplish what I mean?**
**How?**

---

(1) **Why, for my purposes, I cannot work with native OpenSSH?**

For instance, the first two commands in the PS-way of enabling OpenSSH already require admin (my PS is in Spanish):

```
> Get-WindowsCapability -Online | ? Name -like 'OpenSSH*'
Get-WindowsCapability : La operación solicitada requiere elevación.
> Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0
Add-WindowsCapability : La operación solicitada requiere elevación.
```

---

(2) **Why I think it *might* be possible to get an ssh terminal without admin rights in PS?**

1. Because I can already perform several similarly demanding actions as a regular user without admin rights, outside PS:

   1.1. I can ssh from `Msys2` portable

   1.2. I can connect from `putty` (portable)

   1.3. I can transfer via `WinSCP` portable
2. Item (3) below.

---

(3) **How to start an ssh session and issue remote commands from PS**

Install [`Posh-SSH`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Posh-SSH/2.1) [for the current user only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/install-module?view=powershell-7#example-5--install-a-module-only-for-the-current-user).
Then

```
> New-SSHSession -Host xxx.xxx.0.xxx -Credential (Get-Credential)

cmdlet Get-Credential at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Credential

Server SSH Fingerprint
Do you want to trust the fingerprint xx:xx:...
[] Y  [] N  [?] Ayuda (el valor predeterminado es "N"): y
SessionId  Host                                                                               Connected
---------  ----                                                                               ---------
    0      xxx.xxx.0.xxx                                                                        True
> Get-SSHSession
SessionId  Host                                                                               Connected
---------  ----                                                                               ---------
    0      xxx.xxx.0.xxx                                                                        True
> Invoke-SSHCommand -Index 0 -Command "pwd"
Host       : xxx.xxx.0.xxx
Output     : {/home/user1}
ExitStatus : 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 10 has SSH built in since v1809. An OpenSSH-Client is already installed, you can directly use it by calling `ssh`. Try `Get-Command ssh`. It should return `C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe`. You can connect to anything that supports SSH without administrative privileges "out of the box":

```bsh
ssh -l <username> <DNS-Name/IP>
```

There is also an OpenSSH-Server available, but has to be enabled as a feature first. You probably need administrative privileges to enable that.

[MS documentation on enabling OpenSSH-Server](http://web.archive.org/web/20200325080145/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse)

Comment: Gheez, I missed this!!
I only need to work as a client, not server, so this is just what I was looking for.
I thought I also needed to perform some previous setup requiring admin rights, even to work as a client... [`Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse#installing-openssh-with-powershell).
This somewhat puzzles me...

Answer (score 4):

The latest versions of Windows 10 (and 11) have the `ssh.exe` built-in. It does not need to be installed. If you do not have it, you either do not have up-to-date version of Windows 10, or the OpenSSH component was somehow explicitly removed/forbidden.

Anyway, you can download `ssh.exe` manually from [Win32-OpenSSH project](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases). You do not need Administrator permissions for that. It does not need any installation.

---

But on the other hand, if you are not supposed to install software, why are you trying to bypass those restrictions, if you already have PuTTY? Use PuTTY, not `ssh`. If you need a console tool for automation, you can use [PuTTY `plink.exe`](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html). It's a console equivalent of PuTTY. And for automation purposes, it's identical to OpenSSH `ssh` (it does not have all the interactive features of `ssh` – for interactive purposes, use PuTTY).